# How to dynamically change the calendar.eventRender function in order to change the title of all events to an extendedProp

Tags: fullcalendar

TLDR; Want to use custom buttons to define a button which when clicked will update all events setting event.setProp(title,extendedProps.avres).

Long version:
I'm trying to change the titles of all events to extendedProps.avres by changing the eventRender function to update the event.title (thus changing what should be displayed for the event). I've determined I need to set the title prop of the event to change the displayed title, but  am whacking into the wall when trying to dynamically change the eventRender function. Here is the code I've tried which currently silently fails.

```
...
//,buttonText:'AV Resources'
function eventtitleToAvres(info){
  if (info.event.title!=info.event.extendedProps.avres{info.event.setProp(title,extendedProps.avres);}
}
...
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
...
,customButtons:{
  eventtitles:{text:'Titles',click:function(calendar){calendar.eventRender .= eventtitleToDbTitle;}}
  ,eventavres:{text:'AV Resources',click:function(calendar){calendar.eventRender = eventtitleToAvres;}}
  ,eventparticipants:{text:'Participants',click:function(calendar){calendar.eventRender = eventtitleToParticipants;}}
            }
...
```

but clicking the created button AV Resources does nothing. The displayed event titles remain unchanged, event if I cause an event to be updated.. how can I dynamically update the calendar.eventRender function?

Answer (score 0):

eventRender: was the wrong avenue to solve this issue. 
instead I did the following  (using ... for unimportant code related to this solution which do not obfuscate where in the code that it is solved.

```
<script>
    ...
    var eventTextField='dbtext';

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
       ...
        ,customButtons:{
                    eventtitles:{text:'Titles',click: eventtitleToDbTitle}
                    ,eventavres:{text:'AV Resources',click: eventtitleToAvres}
                    ,eventparticipants:{text:'Participants',click: eventtitleToParticipants}
            }
    ,header:left:'prev,next',center:'title',right:'eventtitles,eventavres,eventparticipants'} 
    ...
    });
    calendar.render();
    function changeTitleField(value,index,array){
        value.setProp('title',value.extendedProps[eventTextField]);
    }
    function eventtitleToDbTitle(){
        eventTextField='dbtitle';
        currEvents=calendar.getEvents();
        currEvents.forEach(changeTitleField);
    }
    function eventtitleToAvres(){
        eventTextField='avres';
        currEvents=calendar.getEvents();
        currEvents.forEach(changeTitleField);
    }
    function eventtitleToParticipants(){
        eventTextField='panelists';
        currEvents=calendar.getEvents();
        currEvents.forEach(changeTitleField);
    }

});
</script>
```

So using the above in the document content load function you have to declare the other functions after devlaring the new calendar otherwise it errors and does not work. 
Attempting to use eventRender resulted in a race condition or just a really long running event load with even only 110 events it was still churning after 15 minutes.. Written this way it takes 15-45 seconds to re-render the events, but it does work and I can look at the different fields... My project is to write a tool for organizing programming events for a small fan run (non profit) convention... This allows me to arrange the events then select AV view to look for events needing AV hardware place in rooms without AV resources.. eventually it'll allow me to see a list of participants by name, but that is more complex as the event  panelists field is an array of participant Ids not names.